# presence.activity.game not showing game

Tags: discord, discord.js

I made a `userinfo` command which works fine but the only problem is that it doesn't display the game of the user if they are playing a game. I don't have any error when I use the command. I'm using version `12.1.1` of `discord.js`

```js
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require("discord.js");
const moment = require("moment");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {

    message.delete()

    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || bot.users.cache.get(args[0]) || message.author;
    if (!user) return;
    const userStatus = {
        online: "En ligne",
        idle: "Inactif",
        dnd: "Ne pas déranger",
        offline: "Hors ligne"
    }

    const emojiStatus = {
        online: "<:Online:697378421319270401>",
        idle: "<:Idle:697378421130395749>",
        dnd: "<:DND:697378421386248282>",
        offline: "<:Off:697378421264875594>"
    }

    if (user.bot) {
        isBot = "Yes";
    } else {
        isBot = "No";
    }

    const uiEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(user.username)
        .setColor(message.member.displayHexColor)
        .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({
            dynamic: true
        }))
        .addField("<:Discord:697378425178030171> Username and Tag", user.tag, true)
        .addField("<:ID:697380447876808716> ID", user.id, true)
        .addField(`${emojiStatus[user.presence.status]} Status`, userStatus[user.presence.status], true)
        .addField("<:Game:697380448447234148> Game", `${user.presence.activity ? user.presence.activity.name : "User isn't playing"}`, true)
        .addField("<:Bot:697378421163950152> Bot ?", isBot, true)
        .addField("<:Dis:697380487785873499> Account created at :", moment(user.createdAt).format("LL"), true)
    message.channel.send(uiEmbed);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ui"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presence.activity` is not a thing. You need to use [`presence.activities`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities) which returns an array of [`Activity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity).

You could either just get the first `Activity`:

```js
.addField("<:Game:697380448447234148> Game", `${user.presence.activities[0] ? user.presence.activities[0].name : "User isn't playing"}`, true)
```

Or you could find the `activity` that has the [`type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType) `PLAYING` inside the `activities` array:

```js
const activity = user.presence.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'PLAYING') || null
.addField("<:Game:697380448447234148> Game", `${activity !== null ? activity : "User isn't playing"}`, true)
```